# Programmatically define angular directive with values from a constant?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I currently am defining some directives programmatically from an array of values (`directiveNames` in this example)

```
var directiveNames = ['foo', 'bar'];

directiveNames.forEach(function(name) {
    angular
        .module('myModule')
        .directive(name, buildDirective(name));
});

function buildDirective(name) {
    return function() {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            template: '<p>' + name + '</p>'
        };
    };
}
```

I now want to reuse this array elsewhere.

```
angular
    .module('myModule')
    .constant('directiveNames', ['foo', 'bar']);
```

The problem is, I do not know how I can *inject* this constant into the above snippet. I've tried wrapping the code in a `module.config` and a `module.run` block, but this does not seem to work.

**Is this possible? If so how?**

Answer (score 1):

As a disclaimer I really don't understand why you have to do this and I definitely don't agree with it. The fact is that you're going outside of the Angular lifecycle and essentially meta programming your angular app. Therefore you need a solution that exists primarily outside of Angular. Here's something that should work for you:

```
window.MyDirectiveDefinitions = ['some', 'crazy', 'directives'];
```

Then:

```
angular.module('myApp')
  .constant('directiveDefinitions', window.MyDirectiveDefinitions);
```

Then... :

```
angular.forEach(window.MyDirectiveDefinitions, function(directive) {
  angular.module('myApp')
    .directive(directive, function(Your, Services) {
      // Define your directive.
    });
});
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Given your code you would do this as a new javascript file:

```
var app = angular.module("myModule");
app.constant("myConstants", {
  "constant1": 1,
  "constant2": "two"
});
```

Then you inject "myConstants" into your directives controller and call the values like this:

```
myConstants.constant1
```

Comment: I think you misunderstand. I can't inject it into the directives controller, because I need it for the directive *definition*. The actual name of the directive is derived from that array. In other words, I need to have access to this constant at the point where I do `module.directive()`

Comment: You can make a non-angular javascript file and include it like you would a library script and define directiveNames array there  - I was misled by when you put that you want to "reuse this array elsewhere".

Comment: Hmmm.. that's a *possibility*, although I would really want to avoid making it a global. If you edit your answer to say this instead, I think its worth an upvote. It does in fact answer my question, although I would prefer a more idiomatic angular approach if one exists.

Comment: Yeah - interesting situation - without the injection I really only see it being possible via globals. It is a unique situation - I'd be interested in seeing why you need to on a whim make directives from a set list of names.

Comment: I'm trying to set up a series of (convenience) element-directives to wrap a set of icons. (`<my-icon-name1>`, `<my-icon-name2>`...) where the icons just add classes which are derived from its name. I can (and did) implement this as an attribute directive, passing in the icon name, but I think it would make for very nice looking semantic template code if I do it like this instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
var module = angular.module('myWorld', []);
module.constant('directiveName', ['foo', 'bar']);

var namesOfDirectives = module._invokeQueue.filter(function(a){
  if (a[0] === '$provide' && a[1] === 'constant' && a[2][0] === 'directiveName'){
     return a;    
   }  
})[0][2][1];

console.log(namesOfDirectives);
```

See http://taoofcode.net/studying-the-angular-injector-loading-modules/

...
The _invokeQueue is populated with each service that is added to the module using the familiar angular.module('myModule').controller, angular.module('myModule').directive et al. calls. Each item in the queue is an array with three elements. The first is the provider that will invoke the service, the second is the method on the provider to use and the third element is an array of any arguments passed to the service.
..

Comment: this is very interesting. Cannot try out right now however. I am a bit reluctant to use `_` prefixed methods (they're meant to be private right), but if it works, then should suffice.